# How do I view system tables for a `.MDB` in Access 2010?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

How do I view system tables for a `.MDB` in Access 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Right-click on the header in the navigation pane (by default it says All Tables) and choose `Navigation Options...`
- In the `Navigation Options` window check the `Show System Objects` box and click Ok